# No が in a sentence

Tags: grammar, particles, は-and-が

If there's no が in a sentence, should I assume that は marks both the topic & the action-doer? It seems like that's the case every time I encounter sentences without が.

Answer (score 3):

No. Some easy counter-examples are:

> - 明日は行きます。
>     I will go/come tomorrow.
> - 日本語は話せます。
>     I can speak (at least) Japanese.